# Drop Down list should have (100, 250, All) in JQuery Data table Show Entries drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery data tables to show the contents of a grid.
By Default the "Show entries" dropdown has (10,25,50,100) in it, and on load it renders 10 records per page.
I need it to have (100,250,All) and default rendered number of records per pages should be 100.
How can I achieve that ?

This is my function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    RMDPP.ViewDataSet.Init();
    $('.sortabletable').dataTable({
        columnDefs: [{ orderable: false, "targets": -1 }, { orderable: false, "targets": 1 }] /*1st and last column will not be sorted*/
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pageLength`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength) and [`lengthMenu`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu) options to change the initial page length and change the options in the page length menu.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'lengthMenu': [ [100, 250, -1], [100, 250, 'All'] ],
    'pageLength': 100
    // ... skipped ...
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ovfdg7jj/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks, That works.